# How to get Image From Media Folder in Django

Tags: python, django

I uplaoded An image from fontend to media folder in django.
How can I get that image inside my view.py file. so that I can process that image.
image is saved in /media/images folder

```
 INPUT_IMAGE = '../media/images/inp7.jpg'
```

but when I try to get image using this url its showing file not found. How can I fix it.

Comment: Did you upload this image into some model with ImageField attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Django 3.2:

```py
    from django.conf import settings
    
    INPUT_IMAGE = settings.MEDIA_ROOT / 'inp7.jpg'
```

please check your `MEDIA_ROOT` in `settings.py` and confirm the value is `BASE_ROOT / "`